# Generate MD5 String in java

Tags: java, c#, .net, md5, hashcode

i try to ganerate md5 string in java.I wrote some code an i can ganerate md5 string,but i have problem
first time i show you my code

```
public class MD5Hash
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        computeMD5Hash("dbox#service" + "2014-12-24T18:34:49");
    }

    public static void computeMD5Hash(String password)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create MD5 Hash
            MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

            digest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-16"));
            digest.update(password.getBytes());

            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();
            StringBuffer MD5Hash = new StringBuffer();

            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++)
            {
                String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);

                while (h.length() < 2)
                    h = "0" + h;

                MD5Hash.append(h);
            }

            // result.setText("MD5 hash generated is: " + " " + MD5Hash);
            System.out.println("MD5 hash generated is: " + " " + MD5Hash);

        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

as i said i can recive md5 string but my friend is .net developer and he also wrote code and my md5 string is different .this is a his C# code

```
 public static string CreateMD5(string plain)
 {
     MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
     byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plain);
     byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

somethink is a wrong in my Java code because i want my Md5 string to send server and when i send my md5 string to server i have error -my friend has not...
what is a wrong in my code if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: Your Java code isn't optimized (`StringBuffer`?), but it's working correctly. Why do you think it isn't? I tested it against the published hashes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#MD5_hashes).

Comment: Your code is correct but not very "Java-style". I've created a [Java-style variant](http://vpaste.net/WaenJ) of your code - in case you're interested. In case you're not, just ignore it.

Comment: @Christian Hujer thank you.i inserted your code but i have syntacs error in toHexString method

Comment: @ElliottFrisch because as i said i need this md5 string to send server.and in java code i have error when i try to send and C# did not have any error

Comment: @lucka **What** error?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch sorry i mistaked ,but i recived same md5

Comment: @lucka Then what are you asking?

Comment: my friend recived in C# this Md5 string ea15fbcf2123906e6fcb9f2a3b243492 and me i recived this md5 70F00E5BD872BD73EC6A8B4B8C8C9FEF @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Your friend is using a different `String`.

Comment: @lucka My code ran here before I pasted it, ensuring that it delivers the same String as yours. Syntax errors can come from incomplete paste or using something older than Java 8 (or Java 7 in that case - no lambdas or method references or new API in use). Never mind.

Comment: in current sample digest.update called twice.

Comment: 'echo -n "dbox#service2014-12-24T18:34:49" | md5sum' gives
70f00e5bd872bd73ec6a8b4b8c8c9fef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason for the difference: Encoding

The difference between the programs is in the encoding used to convert the characters of the String into bytes.

#### C# program used `UTF-16LE`

Your friend's C# program is using `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()` which defaults to `UTF-16LE` and thus produces `ea15fbcf2123906e6fcb9f2a3b243492`.

#### Java program used something else

Your Java program is using `String.getBytes()` which defaults to your current Locale's encoding (probably something like `UTF-8` or `Windows-1252`, but obviously something which is backwards compatible to `US-ASCII-7`) and thus produces `70F00E5BD872BD73EC6A8B4B8C8C9FEF`.

#### Agree on something

You have to decide which encoding actually should be used. I'd say that for such use cases, using `UTF-8` is most common and suggest that you both agree on `UTF-8`. But no matter what, you need to agree on something.

#### How to use a specific encoding like `UTF-8` or `UTF-16LE` in Java

Replace the line

```
digest.update(password.getBytes());
```

with

```
digest.update(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
```

or

```
digest.update(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

You can also use charsets beyond those defined in `StandardCharsets`. In that case you need to use the `String` argument version of `String.getBytes()` and deal with `UnsupportedEncodingException`, like this:

```
try {
    digest.update(password.getBytes("ISO-8859-15"));
} catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
}
```

### Nicer version of the program

- Use *varargs* for `main()` so it can be called with `Md5Sum.main()` instead of `Md5Sum.main(new String[0]);` when testing it.
- Refactored `print` into `return`.
- Use a `Formatter` for converting bytes to hex `String` because it's far more convenient: It uses a `StringBuilder` which is faster than a `StringBuffer`, and it offers a `format()` method which makes the conversion much simpler.
- Make variables `final` because we intend to never reassign them.
- Replace `for`-loop with `foreach`-loop because we don't use the index variable.
- Instead of printing the stack trace and continuing, we say we expect `MD5` to be available, and if it is not, it is an internal error of our program and abort. A crashed program causes less damage than a crippled one.

```java
public class Md5Sum {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final String md5sum = md5sum("dbox#service" + "2014-12-24T18:34:49");
        System.out.println("MD5 hash generated is: " + md5sum);
    }
    public static String md5sum2(final String plaintext) {
        try {
            final Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
            final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.update(plaintext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
            for (final byte b : digest.digest())
                formatter.format("%02x", b);
            return formatter.toString();
        } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

### Even nicer version of the program

- Split the function into multiple functions so that they can be used (tested, reused) separately.

```java
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Formatter;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE;

public class Md5Sum {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final String md5sum = md5sum("dbox#service" + "2014-12-24T18:34:49");
        System.out.println("MD5 hash generated is: " + md5sum);
    }

    public static String md5sum(final String plaintext) {
        return toHexString(md5sum(plaintext.getBytes(UTF_16LE)));
    }

    private static byte[] md5sum(final byte... bytes) {
        final MessageDigest digest = createMD5();
        digest.update(bytes);
        return digest.digest();
    }

    private static MessageDigest createMD5() {
        try {
            return MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

    private static String toHexString(final byte... bytes) {
        final Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        for (final byte b : bytes)
            formatter.format("%02X", b);
        return formatter.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On C# sample Encoding.Unicode gives you UTF-16 string to pass to digest, while on Java side UTF-8 string is passed to digest.

Comment: thanks i added digest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-16")); in my code but i also recived different md5 .i have no idea what is a wrong

Comment: I don't know about C#/.Net, but it could be that it uses UTF-16 with Little Endian, and I'm quite sure that Java will give you UTF-16 with Big Endian. You might try to explicitly go for UTF-16LE in case you need the same hash / behavior as the C# program.

Comment: Java String.getBytes()
Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array. Try password.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16"))

Comment: @lonewasp i added this line also but i recived same md5 string :(

Comment: Try UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE, as Christian Hujer suggested. The only things left to check are trailing zeroes going into digest or samll/big letters in MD5 hex dump.

Comment: There's one more thing that could go wrong. The BOM (byte order mark) is optional in UTF-16BE but mandatory in UTF-16LE. If both ends use UTF16-BE but one end issues the BOM and the other doesn't, the bytes will still differ. I recommend you run both versions of the code without calculating the MD5 sum, printing the raw bytes of the converted String first, and check whether that is identical. That helps you isolating whether the problem is something related to MD5 (padding and stuff - shouldn't be) or the String conversion.

Comment: P.S.: That's why in the code that I pasted there are multiple functions. `md5sum2` is just for demo purposes. Your function `copmuteMD5Hash` does 5 things: handling exception, creating MD5, calculating MD5, converting String to bytes, converting bytes to String. That's too much. "A function should do one thing, it should do it well, and it should do it only." Helps you with testing and reuse - testable and reusable are synonyms.